# Nginx and PHP FPM is slow

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

My server have 512 MB memory. nginx.conf setting is

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
#tcp_nopush on;
#tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 3;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}


open_file_cache max=5000 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid    30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

my php fpm config is

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 50

pm.start_servers = 25

pm.min_spare_servers = 8

pm.max_spare_servers = 40
```

I am using one wordpress site. But it's too slow. I have another 512 MB server for the office. It's using apache and it's more faster than nginx + phpfpm. Is there anything wrong in my configuration ?

Memory usages

[image: memory free]

Top results

[image: top results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont start so many php servers initially, perhaps consider testing without this block of code too:

```
open_file_cache max=5000 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid    30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   on;
```

it looks to me like your trying to load too much into ram initially with php though, it also sounds like your website is a little resource intensive based on the memory usage in top, have you considered an opcode cacher like APC? http://pecl.php.net/APC

Answer (score 3):

I use a similar setup with nginx and php-fpm with APC. The Min and Max Servers are a bit high, I also have a virtual machine with about 500mb of memory per machine. After reading https://stephentanner.com/tuning-php-fpm.html I've tuned my machines to the following.

```
pm.max_children = 6
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_requests = 50
```

My machines sit with 4 php-fpm processes at about 60mb each eating about 252mb which leaves more resources for nginx/mysql/whatnot.

Give that a try if it doesn't fit your need exactly tune it a bit more.

Comment: yes, this is quite important, if you have a smallish server (say amazon micro) you will get terrible performance with default configuration. the above config is decent for a tiny server. (1ghz cpu / 512mb ram)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure why you're doing inline gz compression, this takes CPU cycles.. why do you need it?

As anthonysomerset said, lower the number of php children.

Comment: Compression takes almost no time on PCs newer than 15 years.

Comment: Also with 2000-3000 conns/sec?